# windows unattended: windows could not prepare the partition selected for installation

Tags: windows, installation, unattended

I'm trying to create an unattended windows 7 setup DVD. I'm using WSIM to make the XML. I have the felowing issues:

- PE ask me for language, even if it's set in the answer file
- PE ask for to select a disk, even if it's set in the answer file
- After choosing disk 0 from the interface, I get this error:

  - Windows could not prepare the partition selected for installation

Here's the script: http://pastebin.com/vbP556hZ

The PC is fairly simple: one ssd, one dvdr

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to remove the following line:

true

"If you specify a location to install Windows in InstallTo, do not set InstallToAvailablePartition." 
RE: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc709624(v=ws.10).aspx

You already specify to "InstallTo" Disk 0, Partition 1

Good luck

Comment: I removed "InstallToAvailablePartition", the setup doesn't ask for a location and installs! 2/3 of the problem solved. Thnk you!

Comment: 9 years afterwards, thanks for the help, removing "InstallToAvailablePartition" does the trick. Kudos!